# d3js select circle with specific text label

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to select all circles with specific text label and add them new style: `.style("fill", "red")` and onclick method:  `.on("click", function(d) { zoom(d); });` How to do that?

Here is code to generate circles and labels:

```
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
              .data(nodes)
              .enter().append("circle")
              .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
              .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null; })
              .on("click", function(d) { if (focus !== d && d.name.charAt(0) != 'z') zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation(); else if( d.name.charAt(0) === 'z' ) selectSound(d); });  


          var text = svg.selectAll("text")
              .data(nodes)
              .enter().append("text")
              .attr("class", "label")
              .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
              .style("display", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? null : "none"; })
              .text(function(d) { return d.name });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create the circles and texts (by running the code you included above):

```
circle
  .filter(function(d) {
    return d.name == "the-name-of-the-circles-you-want-to-affect";
  })
  .style("fill", "red")
  .on("click", function(d) { zoom(d); });
```

That's how you can get at a subset of the `circles` selection.

However, keep in mind that setting the new 'click' handler on the filtered nodes will override the original click event handler that you initially set on those circles. Maybe that's not a problem; depends on what all is going on in your app etc.

Comment: +1 for noting the click handler will replace the existing one. Suggest adding that you can avoid this by "namespacing" it, e.g. `.on("click.zoom", function(d) { zoom(d); });`